# How to create a prefix code?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request, character-encoding

I am trying to create a demonstration of shannon code in mathematica.
Given a list of lengths (`l1, l2,..lk`) I need to create a list of binary lists (or list of binary strings) that none of them is a prefix of another. For example:
`{1,2,3,3} => {{0},{1,0},{1,1,0},{1,1,1}}`. (I can assure that there is such "code" for the given lengths because they fullfill [Kraft's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality) (an inequality that ensure that you can construct some code for a list of lengths))

It can be done by using some kind of binary tree and where a left edge is 0 and right is 1, but I assume that it can be done with mathematica with no such complex structure.

**Edit - Another example:**
`{1,3,3,4} => {{0},{1,1,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1,1}}`
A pretty problematic and more complex input: 
`{11, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 8, 11, 10, 10}`

Answer (score 2):

```
KraftConditionQ[alphabetLength_Integer, wordLengths : {___Integer}] :=
  Total[alphabetLength^-wordLengths] <= 1;
PrefixCode[alphabet_List, wordLengths : {___Integer}] := 
  PrefixCode[alphabet, SortBy[Tally[wordLengths], First]] /; KraftConditionQ[Length@alphabet, wordLengths];
PrefixCode[alphabet_List, wordLengthsTally : {{_, _} ...}] := 
  Catenate[FoldPairList[PrefixStep[alphabet], {{}}, wordLengthsTally]];
PrefixStep[alphabet_][availablePrefixes : {__List}, {wordLength_, count_}] :=
  If[
    Length[availablePrefixes[[1]]] == wordLength,
    TakeDrop[availablePrefixes, count],
    TakeDrop[
      Flatten[
        Outer[
          Join, 
          availablePrefixes, 
          Tuples[alphabet, wordLength - Length[availablePrefixes[[1]]]], 
          1], 
        1], 
      count]]
```

Some checks:

```
test1 = {1, 3, 3, 4};
test2 = {11, 6, 5, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 6, 7, 6, 8, 11, 10, 10};

PrefixCode[{0, 1}, test1]
```

`{{0},{1,0,0},{1,0,1},{1,1,0,0}}`

```
PrefixCode[{0, 1}, test2]
```

`{{0,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,1,1},{0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,1},{0,1,1,0},{0,1,1,1},{1,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1,0},{1,0,0,1,1},{1,0,1,0,0,0},{1,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0,1,1},{1,0,1,1,0,0},{1,0,1,1,0,1},{1,0,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,1,1,1},{1,1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0},{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1},{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0},{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1}}`